# Drools: Can't declare new type (with field) in .drl file

Tags: types, field, declaration, drools

I cannot add fields to new type declarations. Do I need an actual Java class for every type declaration in a .drl file? I thought those were generated by Drools?

This works:

```
package tests

declare Person
end
```

Now add a field (type doesn't matter):

```
package tests 

declare Person
    age : int
end
```

And it throws following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty()Z
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.resolveType(PackageBuilder.java:1606)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.fillFieldTypes(PackageBuilder.java:1672)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.processTypeDeclarations(PackageBuilder.java:2008)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.mergePackage(PackageBuilder.java:1272)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:869)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:466)
at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:694)
at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:51)
at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:40)
at RuleTest.setUp(RuleTest.java:35)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

It's thrown at the "Testrules.drl" line:

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

    kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource( "Testrules.drl" ), ResourceType.DRL );
    ...
}
```

Using
    Eclipse 3.4.2, 
    Drools 5.5.0 Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method String.isEmpty() seems to have been introduced in 1.6 (Java 6). Removing the old Java VM and installing the current version (Java 7) fixed the problem.